# php mysql - get product thumbnail image of a product

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce, I'm trying to retrieve thumbnail image of a product, I've tried to use woocommerce api but it did not have any parameters for thumbnail, I've searched in database and found it in wp_postmeta table, but the structure of meta_value is very difficult to read, for example:

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:694;s:6:"height";i:660;s:4:"file";s:69:"2017/11/روغن-ذرت-زرین-1.8-لیتری-33150-26500اصل.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:4:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:69:"روغن-ذرت-زرین-1.8-لیتری-33150-26500اصل-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:69:"روغن-ذرت-زرین-1.8-لیتری-33150-26500اصل-300x285.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:285;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:69:"روغن-ذرت-زرین-1.8-لیتری-33150-26500اصل-150x143.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:143;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:69:"روغن-ذرت-زرین-1.8-لیتری-33150-26500اصل-300x285.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:285;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"1";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

it has all images of a product with different sizes, the question is, how can I read this in php and get the image src I want from this?

Comment: on wichi page you want to retrive the thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That format is serialize array, you can unserialize it using WordPress function [`maybe_unserialize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize)

`maybe_unserialize( $your_meta_value );`

Comment: thanks for reply , I did not include any wordpress class, how can I import the classes that I need to access this function ?

Comment: always welcome, you just need to pass `meta_value` in that functions, let me know if you need any further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment on @Aiyaz's Answer, 
to include wordpress functions, just use
`require_once("wordpress-folder-path/wp-load.php");`
where wordpress-folder-path is the path to your wordpress installation.

But you could probably get away with using php's native `unserialize($data)` function.